# flutter save page state after routing

Tags: flutter, setstate, state-management

how can i save page state after routing, when routing and going back to the concern page it has the initial state when starting the app, every modification on the page (setState) is gone. how to solve it and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Database or shared preferences to save your data. Then load the stored data and display corresponding layout.